# ASP.NET sequential layout problem

Tags: asp.net, layout

This is a bit hard to explain. I have a website with a lot of links to other webshops, each of these webshops are grouped by a category. I want to make an "efficient" layout, saving screen real estate. I have tried using a listview/gridview but it seems to use too much space when there are only a few items below each category. All my rows have similar height, and thus using too much space when there are only a few shops in a single category.

What i got:

```
GROUP 1      GROUP2       GROUP3
shop1        shop5        shop7
shop2        shop6        shop8
shop3                     shop9
shop4
```

What i want:

```
GROUP 1      GROUP 2     shop8
shop1        shop5       shop9
shop2        shop6       shop10 
shop3        GROUP 3     GROUP 4
shop4        shop7       shop11
```

that is i want to save my screen real estate doing it this way, anyone got a solution to how this could be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using datalists with columns, but then still not solved the issue on compacting the layout

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can achieve it with CSS. But I'm not sure how